# Ruby instance_eval and const_missing

Tags: ruby, dsl

I would like to call `const_missing` in an `instance_eval`, but seem to be missing something:

```
class A
  def self.const_missing(c)
    puts "Constant missing: #{c}"
  end

  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    puts "Method missing: #{m}"
  end       
end

# Works:
a = A.new
a.myMethod # OK: "Method missing: myMethod" 
a.MYCONST  # Sort of OK: "Method missing: MYCONST"

# Doesn't work
a.instance_eval {
  myMethod # OK: "Method missing: myMethod"
  MYCONST  # uninitialized constant MYCONST (NameError)
}
```

Q: Where does the `const_missing` call in the `instance_eval` go? How can redirect it to class `A`? (Ruby 1.9.3 if this matters)

Context: I am writing a small DSL, where upper-case letters are used as state names.

```
DSL.evaluate {
  ENTER_STATE_A
  WAIT_FOR_INPUT
}
```

These should be mapped to methods, but I would like to keep them upper case.

Comment: If your Ruby DSL requires you to contravene the established [Ruby syntax](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants#Constants) for defining constants, then you are digging yourself into a giant hole.

Comment: That is why I would like to have any change really just inside an instance_eval. The DSL files are loaded at a well defined stage and don't mix with code.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to access a constant w/ `a.MYCONST` which ruby is interpreting as a method. You instead need to use `::` along w/ access the class itself and not the instance of that class:

```
a = A.new
a.instance_eval {
  self::class::MYCONST # => Constant missing: MYCONST
}
```

It seems that when calling `MYCONST` inside of `instance_eval` it's being caught by `Object.const_missing`. For example if you override it you'll see the behavior you're after:

```
def Object.const_missing(c)
  puts "Constant missing: #{c}"
end 

a = A.new
a.instance_eval {
  MYCONST # => Constant missing: MYCONST
}
```

I don't recommend actually doing this though. I'm only showing this to illustrate what's happening.

Comment: Yes, I got that wrong. But I would like to write just `MYCONST` and delegate to a.

Comment: Thanks Kyle! Is there a way to monkey_patch const_missing on Object, while I am in the instance_eval?

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek I'm honestly not sure. There may be a way to do it without having to monkey patch `Object`. Not sure if this would work but you may want to look into [Refinements](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you do

```
a.MYCONST
```

you got `Method missing: MYCONST` (and not `Constant missing: MYCONST`).

You should do the following:

```
a.instance_eval {
  myMethod
  A::MYCONST
}
```

Comment: Not helping, I don't want to put DSL::ENTER_STATE_A

Comment: That's a bit harsh. His answer would help you if you'd look at it. Constants exist on the Class or Singleton level. You're expecting an instance level method call to trigger a class level constant. You have to call the constant through the class hence why you need A::MYCONST

Comment: True, I understand, sorry for not being more open to the advice. But A::MYCONST is really not what I am looking for as a solution. Technically, I don't think it is a big problem to go from class level to my instance (Thread local storage was my thought)